# Sed replacement

Tags: bash, sed

I would like to add a sed command in a bash script which replace

```
#archive_command = ''
```

to

```
archive_command = 'rsync -a %p barman@$BACKUP_SERVER_IP:$INCOMING_WALS_DIRECTORY/%f'
```

I am not an expert and I am always getting errors. I guess is something about single and double quotes

```
sudo sed -i "s!#archive_command = ''!archive_command = 'rsync -a %p barman@$BACKUP_SERVER_IP:$INCOMING_WALS_DIRECTORY/%f'!" "/my/archive"
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your sed command looks like it should work. Does it work if you use it directly, rather than with `sudo`?

Comment: Please add the errors you're getting.

Comment: You problem is that ! (exclamation) is a history search marker

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sudo sed -i "/^#archive_command = /s|.*|archive_command = 'rsync -a %p barman@\$BACKUP_SERVER_IP:\$INCOMING_WALS_DIRECTORY/%f'|" file
```

Don't quote if you want those variables to expand:

```
sudo sed -i "/^#archive_command = /s|.*|archive_command = 'rsync -a %p barman@$BACKUP_SERVER_IP:$INCOMING_WALS_DIRECTORY/%f'|" file
```

Answer (score 0):

...or to make it more readable:):

```
sed "s/\(#\)\(.[^']*\)\('\)\('\)/\2\3rsync -a %p barman@\$BACKUP_SERVER_IP:\$INCOMING_WALS_DIRECTORY\/%f\4/" file
```